# submitting input into AFL fuzzer

Tags: disassembly, binary-analysis, linux, fuzzing

I have some questions about the [AFL Fuzzer](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/afl/):

1. How does the AFL Fuzzer know where to inject the payload in the code I compile? For instance if I want to inject it in a specific parameter, how do I do it?
2. As I understood, if I put all test cases in the input directory it knows to build randomly injections based on that input, yes?
3. I saw a video shows that if for instance there are two inputs in the code, so in the test case each line is for each input. Is that correct? Since I want put a full message (for example HTTP request) into one variable, so how do I do it ?
4. I have compiled everything correctly but for some reason it does not find any new paths. In addition, if I do not put the `-m none` I get the following error : "Fork server crashed with signal 6".
5. I don't understand when to put `@@`.

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. As far as I understand AFL, it mutates whatever input is provided and is able to _generate_ input which triggers faulty behavior. The way it does that is by exploiting the fact that `fork()` keeps the full state of the program prior to the `fork()` and so it's relatively cheap to follow different execution paths simply by mutating the input as it goes. The author of AFL even provides a corpus of image files _generated_ by AFL "from thin air" simply by fuzzing some image processing tool and generating/mutating input for it.